# How to call a main class in a jar package from eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

Currently, there is bat file that calls the main class in a jar file. Now I want to run it using eclipse. How do I configure the eclipse to run it?

I have tried the Run > External tools > External tools configuration. But I don't know what to type in...

```
@echo off

set MODULE2_HOME=%~dp0..
set JAVA_HOME=C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_71


set CLASSPATH="%MODULE2_HOME%/classes;%MODULE2_HOME%/lib/*;%MODULE2_HOME%/lib/oracle/*;%MODULE2_HOME%/lib/aspose/*;%MODULE_HOME%/aspose/*"
set SETUP_PROPERTIES="%MODULE2_HOME%\conf\setup.properties"

set PATH=%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%PATH%

java -cp %CLASSPATH% -Dsetup.properties=%SETUP_PROPERTIES% com.module.fast.main.Module2Main %*
```

How do I configure eclipse to run exactly like this command?

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a batch file which will run in Windows. You can go to the command prompt and run the batch file using .bat. You do not need Eclipse. You can run the java class in eclipse. Still if you want to run, you can check the following screenshot.

[image]

While configuring, make sure to give the complete path of batch file. If the bat file needs extra commandline params, you can give the batch file location with space and the command line parameters separated with spaces.

It does not work to run the jar file which contains main class, you have to give the working directory location.